# When I click on a button click from my webform, it never goes to the MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

Trying to Integrate MVC 4 Razor into Webforms website, followed 
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_MVCandWebForms.html 
On my WebForms Application's web.config

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"
        type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup,System.Web.WebPages.Razor,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="host"
          type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection,System.Web.WebPages.Razor,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
          requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages"
          type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection,System.Web.WebPages.Razor,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
          requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory,System.Web.Mvc,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>

  <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <pages validateRequest ="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
  </pages>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">    
      <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
  </compilation>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

  <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add  name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*"
            preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have followed the exact same procedure from other blog's too but with no success.
Global.asax

```
namespace MVCWebFormIntegrate
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

}
}
```

Have Referenced the Dll's in my webform project

```
System.web.Mvc
System.web.Routing
System.web.Abstractions
```

But when i click on a button click from my webform, it never goes to the MVC view

```
Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
```